# Converting a Differential Equation into a system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the procedure for converting a single differential equation into a system to then be solved by matrix methods. I've looked it up on a few websites but I still don't understand what is being done.

For example this -

$2y'' + 5y' - 3y = 0$

$y(0) = -4$

$y'(0) = 9$

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2y'' + 5y' - 3y = 0, y(0) = -4, y'(0) = 9$$

- Let $y = x_1$
- $x_1' = y' = x_2$
- $x_2' = y'' = -\dfrac{5}{2}y' + \dfrac{3}{2} y = -\dfrac{5}{2}x_2 + \dfrac{3}{2}x_1, x_1(0) = -4, x_2(0) = 9$

So, our new system is:

$$x_1' = x_2 \\x_2' = \dfrac{3}{2}x_1 -\dfrac{5}{2}x_2$$

With $x_1(0) = -4, x_2(0) = 9$.

Comment: Why did you divide through by 2 and also why did the sign of the first term change to -ve?

Comment: Recall, we want $y''$ by itself and it has a factor of $2$. Also, we want $y''$ on the LHS by itself, so we bring the other terms to the RHS. Clear?

Comment: Yes, I get it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Define $x_1=y,x_2=y^\prime$. Then, 
$$x_1^\prime=x_2,\quad x_1(0)=-4\\
x_2^\prime=\dfrac{3}{2}x_1-\dfrac{5}{2}x_2,\quad x_2(0)=9$$
This is the system of differential equations for the given equation.

In general, if the differential equation is $ay^{\prime\prime}+by^\prime+cy+d=0$, then we can write $x_1=y,x_2=y^\prime$, giving, with initial value conditions $x_1(a)=b,x_2(A)=B$:
$$x_1^\prime=x_2,\quad x_1(a)=b\\
x_2^\prime=\dfrac{-\left(d+cx_1+bx_2\right)}{a},\quad x_2(A)=B$$